# How to do calculation and print values in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to do perform some calculations and print values in a div tag.

I want to calculate sum of `sum1 = (total * total2) + jsvar1;` and `sum2 = ( total1 * total2 ) + jsvar1;`.

Next, I want to display `sum1` and `sum2` value in the html div tag.

How could I accomplish this with what I have? I would be very grateful if anyone can help me to do this. Thank you very much.

---

Here is what I have so far:

```
jsvar1 = <?php 
  $sql9 = mysql_query("select room_rate from room_category where hotel_id='".$hotel_id."' and room_type = '".$var_value."' ");  
  $res9 = mysql_fetch_array($sql9);
  $roomrate = $res9["room_rate"];
  echo $roomrate;
?>;
document.write(jsvar1);


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#roomOptions #select1').change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('#roomOptions #select1').each(function() {
            total+=parseInt($(this).val());

        });
        $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total').html(total);
    });


    $('#roomOptions #select2').change(function() {
        var total1 = 0;
        $('#roomOptions #select2').each(function() {
            total1+=parseInt($(this).val());

        });
        $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total1').html(total1);
    });



    $('#roomOptions #select3').change(function() {
        var total2 = 0;
        $('#roomOptions #select3').each(function() {
            total2+=parseInt($(this).val());

        });
        $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total2').html(total2);
    });


});
```

Comment: I want know how to calculate these values?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your total variables outside of change events and in that event you calculate the sum:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var total, total1, total2;
    $('#roomOptions #select1').change(function() {
        total = 0;
        $('#roomOptions #select1').each(function() {
            total+=parseInt($(this).val());

        });
        $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total').html(total);
        calcualteSum1();
    });
    $('#roomOptions #select2').change(function() {
        total1 = 0;
        $('#roomOptions #select2').each(function() {
            total1+=parseInt($(this).val());

        });
        $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total1').html(total1);
        calcualteSum2();
    });

    $('#roomOptions #select3').change(function() {
        total2 = 0;
                $('#roomOptions #select3').each(function() {
            total2+=parseInt($(this).val());

        });
        $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total2').html(total2);
        calcualteSum1();
        calcualteSum2();
    });

    function calcualteSum1() {
        $('#sum').html((total * total2) + jsvar1);
    }
    function calcualteSum2() {
        $('#sum').html((total1 * total2) + jsvar1);
    }
});
```